# Conjugate Gradient Methods problem

Tags: numerical-methods

I have one proble to solve.
[image: figure]

I have to determine $x$ that minimizes $d$. $C$ is the centroid of the figure. This is the problem given problem my numerical analysis class which is something that I did not learn in class. However I do not even understand the question. Can anyone explain this?? I also need a detailed explanation of centroid too. Thanks!